# How to select and rotate object in blender 3.1 with bpy and python?

Tags: python, scripting, scene

I'm trying to select and rotate an object in a frame_change_pre-handler.
Here is the function:

```
def frame_handler(self, context, dummy):
    self.max_frame = 200
    slow = 45
    axis = "X"
    rotVal = -slow
    scn = context   #->instead of bpy.context.scene, which I tried before     
    frm = scn.frame_current
    print(f"current  frame: {scn.frame_current}") #-> this works correct
    
    cup = bpy.data.objects["cup"] 
    print(f"cup name = {cup.name}") # -> this works fine!

    try:

      if ((scn.frame_current > 1) &  (scn.frame_current % 5) == 0):
          print("starting cup  rotation")

          bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

          cup.select_set(True)
          bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cup

          bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(rotVal), orient_axis=axis)
         
         
          bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_byx_name(type="Rotation")
          print("cup  rotated")
        
          bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    except Exception as e:
        print (f"error {e}")
```

The line with bpy.ops.transform.rotate
gives the error:

```
error Operator bpy.ops.transform.rotate.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

My blender version is 3.1.

Is there maybe a simpler way to rotate an object in blender 3
(like cup.rotate(x,y,z) or so)?

Thank you!

I made a blend-file with some minor code changes:

[image]

Instead of:
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(rotVal), orient_axis=axis)

I tried this:
cup.rotation_euler.rotate_axis('X',math.radians(rotVal  ))

but the error still stays the same.

edit:
maybe I could ask even more precise:
what would be the correct context and how can I set it to the
correct context, so that blender executes the rotation as
desired?

Comment: You should modify the object matrix directly instead of using `bpy.ops`

Comment: Thank you. What is the python statement for that?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in one point:
the error was not the same with the modified statements,
because I just put the statements into a wrong function.

So this statements

```
 cup = bpy.data.objects["cup"] 
 cup.rotation_euler.rotate_axis('X',math.radians(rotVal ))
```

already execute the rotation as desired and do not lead into
a context problem.

It would be worth to find out anyway, why bpy.ops.transform.rotate
leads into an error, but this is another question.

I made an update of the blender-file:

[image]

which works fine now.